# Sonata ModelAutocompleteType result affected by getFilterParameters

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-3.4, sonata, symfony-sonata

I have this form field of a type `ModelAutocompleteType` that is supposed to show the result filtered by the "search" datagrid field of related admin:

```
class OperationAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
  // ...

  protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
  {
    $formMapper
      ->add('business', ModelAutocompleteType::class, [
        'label' => 'Business',
        'property' => 'search'
      ]);
  }

  // ...
}
```

In this related "business" admin I have few filters defined as:

```
class BusinessAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
  // ...

  protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
  {
    $datagridMapper
      ->add('search', CallbackFilter::class, [
        'label' => 'Search',
        'show_filter' => true,
        'advanced_filter' => false,
        'callback' => function($qb, $alias, $field, $value) {
           if (!$value['value']) return;
           // ...

           return true;
        }
      ])
      ->add('state', ChoiceFilter::class, [
        'label' => 'State', 
        'show_filter' => true,
        'advanced_filter' => false,
        'field_options' => ['choices' => Business::STATES],
        'field_type' => 'choice'
      ]);
  }

  // ...
}
```

Now, if I set the default "state" datagrid field value using `getFilterParameters` to filter business list by state on initial page load:

```
  public function getFilterParameters()
  {
    $this->datagridValues = array_merge([
      'state' => ['type' => '', 'value' => 'active']
    ], $this->datagridValues);

    return parent::getFilterParameters();
  }
```

The related `ModelAutocompleteType` form field's result will also be filtered by "state" field even tho it's `property` is set to `search`.

How do I apply default filter values JUST to list view and nothing else? And why `ModelAutocompleteType` result depends on other datagrid fields even tho property is set to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I left `getFilterParameters` method in to filter list by default, which is what I wanted:

```
public function getFilterParameters()
{
  $this->datagridValues = array_merge([
    'state' => ['type' => '', 'value' => 'active']
  ], $this->datagridValues);

  return parent::getFilterParameters();
}
```

Unfortunatelly, that was also affecting `ModelAutocompleteFilter` and `ModelAutocompleteType` results, filtering them by 'active' state too, which I did not want.

To solve that I had to pass a `callback` property to `ModelAutocompleteType` field, to reset datagrid state value:

```
class OperationAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
  // ...

  protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
  {
    $formMapper
      ->add('business', ModelAutocompleteType::class, [
        'label' => 'Business',
        'property' => 'search',
        'callback' => [$this, 'filterAllBusinessesCallback']
      ]);
  }

  public function filterAllBusinessesCallback(AdminInterface $admin, $property, $value)
  {
    $datagrid = $admin->getDatagrid();
    $datagrid->setValue($property, null, $value);
    $datagrid->setValue('state', null, null);
  }

  // ...
}
```